# Como validar insert com relacionamento many to many

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, validation

Tenho 3 tabelas, uma de tipos de veículos: Carro, motocicleta.
Uma tabela de marcas: Honda, Ferrari
Outra associativa, chamada de marca_tipo_veiculo.

A marca Honda por exemplo, possui carros e motos. Então ela tem dois registros na tabela marca_tipo_veiculo, um para moto, outro para carro.

Eu preciso fazer uma validação, que não permita que o nome de marca se duplique na tabela de marcas, porém ela pode estar associada com mais de um tipo de veículo e essa associação também só pode ser feita uma única vez para cada tipo de veículo, como o exemplo da Honda.

Fiz dessa forma, porém acredito que possa ser melhorado em uma única validação:

```php
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $brand = Brand::where('nome', $request->nome);

        if (!$brand->exists()) {

            $request->validate([
                'nome' => 'required|string|unique:marcas',
                'tipo_veiculo_id' => 'required|int|exists:tipos_veiculos',
            ]);

            $newBrand = Brand::create($request->all());

            $newBrand->typesVehicles()->attach($request->tipo_veiculo_id);

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Tipo de veículo cadastrado com sucesso!'], 201);
        }

        $brand = $brand->first();

        /*
         * valida que o id do tipo de veículo exista.
         * valida a unicidade composta de marca e tipo de veículo.
         */
        $request->validate([
            'tipo_veiculo_id' =>
                'exists:tipos_veiculos,id|unique:marca_tipo_veiculo,tipo_veiculo_id,NULL,id,marca_id,' . $brand->id
        ]);

        $brand->typesVehicles()->attach($request->tipo_veiculo_id);

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Tipo de veículo cadastrado com sucesso!'], 201);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um `Form Request` customizado.

```
// Para criar um `Form Request` execute o comando abaixo:
php artisan make:request CreateBrandRequest
```

Form Request:

```
class CreateBrandRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return auth()->check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nome' => 'required|string|unique:marcas',
            'tipo_veiculo_id' => 'required|int|exists:tipos_veiculos',
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function create(CreateBrandRequest $request)
{
    $brand = Brand::create($request->all());
    // O método sync garante que não terá registros duplicados.
    $brand->typesVehicles()->sync([$request->input('tipo_veiculo_id')]);

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Tipo de veículo cadastrado com sucesso!'], 201);
}
```